# How to create a column with a value of 1 if another column goes past a threshold from one year to another in panel data , 0 otherwise in R

Tags: r, dplyr, case, transition, panel

[image]

I want to create a column for if the value went over the threshold of 10 for example as 1 if the previous year did not go over the threshold otherwise it's 0 as shown as in the last column of the sample image. This would be done for only the same unique items across all the years

my intiution is use dplyr and casewhen but don't know how to write the code for the case when part

```
df <- df %>%
group_by(unique, year) %>%
mutate(value turned = case_when(value10 == 1 in year but not in previous year) ~ 1, otherwise 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(unique=c(rep("10ab",3),rep("12cc",3)), year=rep(2017:2019,2),
                 value10 = c(0,1,1,1,1,1))

df %>% group_by(unique) %>% arrange(year) %>% 
  mutate(value_turned = as.integer(value10 == 1 & lag(value10, default = 1) == 0)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% arrange(unique) 

#> # A tibble: 6 × 4
#>   unique  year value10 value_turned
#>   <chr>  <int>   <dbl>        <int>
#> 1 10ab    2017       0            0
#> 2 10ab    2018       1            1
#> 3 10ab    2019       1            0
#> 4 12cc    2017       1            0
#> 5 12cc    2018       1            0
#> 6 12cc    2019       1            0
```